# Localhost not loading React app despite Docker container listed as "up"

Tags: reactjs, docker, react-scripts

Before I dive into the problem, I want to note that neither I nor my team have made any updates to the Docker configuration of our project in the last few days, and that my containers were running as usual until today. The only change I have made is to upgrade to OS X Big Sur over the weekend.

We have 3 containers in our project, running our mongodb, api, and frontend. Today I restarted the containers to test something, and all 3 containers completed their setup without throwing any errors, and running `docker-compose ps` shows all 3 containers as running:
[image: Running containers]

However, navigating to localhost:3000 immediately bombs out as though the server isn't running. (Firefox gives a "The connection was reset" error and Chrome says "This page isn't working: localhost didn't send any data")

I can't tell how my frontend container appears to be running yet not running. The logs don't really give much info either:

```
frontend_1  | > frontend@0.1.0 start /app
frontend_1  | > react-scripts start
```

My react scripts version is still 3.4.0, so [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688) is not the culprit (in that example, there is an exit code of 0, whereas in mine there is no exit code).